# Query to update row value in next blank column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `StencilStorage` and it has fields that look like this.

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a stored procedure that will update the table and set `PCB_ID` equal to some irrelevant number wherever the next available slot is, sorting the table from low->high by `UNIQID`. I have the following so far. The next available slot is labeled as `0` as shown in row 5 in the table above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_to_storage
(
    @PCB_ID integer
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Tooling.StencilStorage
    SET PCB_ID = @PCB_ID 
    WHERE
GO;
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What condition will satisfy as an available slot? Is it pcb_id = 0?

Comment: @ShamvilKazmi Yes, in this case it will be PCB_ID = 0, will update the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_to_storage
(
    @PCB_ID integer
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Tooling.StencilStorage
    SET PCB_ID = @PCB_ID 
    WHERE UNIQID = (SELECT TOP 1 UNIQID FROM Tooling.StencilStorage WHERE PCB_ID = 0 ORDER BY UNIQID)

GO;
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate the help.